Google Apps Script HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile seems to not be working
I've been using Google Apps Script for years.  I've been successfully using HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile for months.  But a few weeks ago, code that has been working for months stopped working.  No HTML is rendered at all.
I created a very small test case.
test.gs
function doIt()
{
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test');
}

test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
     <input type="text" id="id" placeholder="Input" style="width: 200px;"> 
  </body>
</html>

The code is here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R0EZaHZyR9uUOU6iawc56Tq_lDAmU1aNvWqy9Emluq8/edit?usp=sharing
The problem:  No HTML is rendered.  Any ideas?

Please be more descriptive than "stopped working". See reproducible subsection of [mre]

In a comment to my answer, you mentioned that the problem occurs no matter what you try. Unfortunately, as I explained in my answer, the code provided doesn't work, and the question also lacks important debugging details. Please add the deployment details, the execution logs, and the web browser console logs.

This is not being deployed as a web service.  It is simply a standalone Google Sheets script.  So, I open Google Sheets, then I go into the Apps Script editor, run the function doIt, and I should get HTML rendered on the Google Sheet.  And, until a few weeks ago, I did.  But now, I get nothing.

The name of the function on the server-side code needs to be corrected. Instead of doIt, use doGet. Also, the function misses the return of an HTML Output object.
For details, see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web.

The below example uses doGet as the server-side function name and returns an HTML Output object.
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<p>Hello world!</p>');
}

You should have created a deployment, just to remind yourself. To test the above code, create a new version or use the test deployment URL.

Thanks for replying.  Unfortunately, it is not that simple.  The Google Apps Script function can be named anything - it doesn't have to be doGet.  The problem is that no HTML is rendered regardless of what I name the function or what I do.

@TomSteppe Please add evidencie of your claim
